# Router firewall blocking local ssh access using local-link ipv6

Tags: ssh, firewall, ipv6, link-local-address

The [question was originally posted at ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1487210/1188532), as originally sounded as being Ubuntu related. But it appears more related to subjects like networking, firewall, etc. as the results differ if router firewall is on or off.

**The problem:** I can use the local-link ipv6 for ssh (or ping) just if my router firewall is off.

The firewall is also blocking my temporary public IPv6 from being accessed from the external network. But for now, I am considering just using local-link ipv6 as it provides a fixed/permanent (not temporary) address.

I can remotely access my Ubuntu 22.04 PC from my Windows notebook on my local network using SSH using a public IPv6 address even when firewall is on.

```
ssh <username>@<public ipv6 address> -p <port>
```

Or `ping` it without a problem.

As local-link ipv6 is permanent (`valid_lft forever`), it would be handy to use it. But it does not work with

```
ssh -6 <username>@<local-link ipv6 address>%<iternfaceLANNumber> -p <port>
```

I just got

> Connection timed out

I also cannot ping with

```
ping @<local-link ipv6 address>%<iternfaceLANNumber>
```

It returns the destined host unreachable

The <iterfaceLANNumber> I got at Windows PC, and I am certain it is correct. And I am sure all the command lines above are correct. When I deactivate the router’s firewall, they (using local-link ipv6) work perfectly.

---

I am sorry, my knowledge on the subject is very basic yet…

1. In my understanding, the link-local ipv6 is static and only available locally specifically as a way to safely enabling local access. And should be our first in line, if the idea is to just having local access…

Shouldn't link-local ipv6 be available in the local network even with a firewall (at router)? Why should a router firewall block it? **How can I enable the use of link-local ipv6 keeping the router’s firewall on**?

2. I already learned we can set firewall at the devices level, [`ufw` on](https://superuser.com/a/1071879/1276320), for example. Originally, my Ubuntu has no `ufw` active. Activating it and releasing the specific port I set for ssh does not solve the problem. Currently, `sudo ufw status` shows the specified port is allowed from anywhere

Even with the alternative to set firewalls at devices level, I do not feel comfortable simply putting the firewall off for my entire network (at the router). And I suppose that’s not a good idea…

The router menu shows just ways to set the firewall for ipv6 as active/deactivated, no way to set it/or block it specifically for ports, devices, etc. I see options for port forwarding using ipv6, but I understand as we are talking about local-link address being available locally, they are unrelated… Not sure if relevant, but dhcpv6 is not active according to router's menu.

3. Is it possible that I messed up the Ubuntu’s local configuration… I was making some modifications, like trying to implement UIE-64 naming and changing ipv6 privacy configurations to see if I can set a static public ipv6 as an alternative, with no success… does the problem relate to it?

at Ubuntu, I have:

- edited the `<networkName>.nmconnection` file at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

  - at `[ipv6]`
  - `addr-gen-mode=eui64`
- `nmcli connection edit <network>`

  - `set ipv6.addr-gen-mode 0`
  - `set ipv6.ip6-privacy 1`
- [edited  `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf`]

  - `net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.accept_ra = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.autoconf=1`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.use_tempaddr=0`
- Edited the `.yaml` file at `/etc/netplan`

  - `network:`
    *  `version: 2`
    *   `ethernets:`
    *     `<WLancode>:`
    *       `dhcp6: false`
    *       `ipv6-privacy: off`
    *       `ipv6-address-generation: eui64`
    *       `accept-ra: false`
    *   `renderer: NetworkManager`

Any help is appreciated.